# Django how to load statics inside a python file

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to load a an image from static to a from element

I tried to load it inside my `forms.py` as a style attribute

```
widget=forms.Select(attrs={
            'style': 'background: url("{% static \'/img/Arrow_bottom.png\' %}") 2rem / 2rem no-repeat #eee;'
            })
```

but it's interpreted in the browser as a text `"background: url("{% static '/img/Arrow_bottom.png' %}")`

I want `"background: url("static_dir/img/Arrow_bottom.png")`

how can I load statics to my forms.py file or to the css file

Comment: Why not just set a class and get the image to show up with the CSS?

Comment: I fixed it by adding a style tag in my html file
`<style>
    .styled-select select {
        background: url("{% static '/svg/Arrow_bottom.png' %}") 2rem / 2rem no-repeat #eee;
    }
</style>`

but I still want to know what you mean with set a class and get the image to show up with the CSS?

Comment: Just do `attrs={'class': 'background-image'}` and then in your CSS handle the path to the image.

Comment: I can't load static in the css file it's the same thing

Comment: You don't need to. You just include the relative path because the CSS already is a static file.

Comment: ah ok I got it.